# Which woman false prophet is the Baal Haturim referring to?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-reading, parashat-reeh, false-prophet

Deuteronomy 13:2 says:

> כִּֽי־יָק֤וּם בְּקִרְבְּךָ֙ נָבִ֔יא א֖וֹ חֹלֵ֣ם חֲל֑וֹם וְנָתַ֥ן אֵלֶ֛יךָ א֖וֹת א֥וֹ מוֹפֵֽת׃
>
> If there appears among you a prophet or a dream-diviner and he gives you a sign or a portent

The Baal Haturim writes very cryptically on this:

> בקרבך- בגימטריה  זו האשה
>
> Among you - This has the same numerical value as "this is the woman"  .

This implies the false prophet among you means "the woman". Who is the Bal Haturim referring to?

Comment: Maybe something generic like http://www.academia.edu/860378/The_Woman-as-witch_stereotype_in_Early_Modern_England_Continental_Europe_and_New_England

Comment: Just stumbled upon this site for the first time. No one above mentions this, but it seems to me that the Baal HaTurim may be suggesting that "be-kirbecha" is a reference to "inside the womb".

Answer (score 9):

The parsha deals with a false prophet and uses exclusively male verbs. This might lead one to think the relevant laws only apply to a male prophet. Therefore the Midrash [Sifrei 83:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.83.3/) says:

> בקרבך. לרבות האשה.
>
> "in your midst": to include a woman.

I guess this word is considered superfluous enough to be adding something, which Chazal say that even a female false prophet is liable.

The Baal Haturim wants to show the gematria of the word shows a hint to where this drash came from. I find the exact phraseology of האשה, the location of the source, and the frequency of the Baal Haturim to do this style of gematrias compelling evidence that this is his intent.

Comment: intresting since my Bal Haturim writes Sifri at the end

Comment: @sam so does mine; that tipped me off. I wouldn't use that as a proof though as it may be a recent addition.

Answer (score 4):

It seems Eliyahu Munk explains it that it is referring to the founder of cristianity's mother

From https://www.sefaria.org/Tur_HaAroch,_Deuteronomy.13.2.1/en

> [There is a bracket by the publisher in my edition that calls attention to a gematriya our author (did not completely) publish in his commentary known as Baal Haturim in which the letters of the word נביא , prophet, (63) are shown to have the same numerical value as the word ובנה, “and her son.” The author did publish the other half of this, i.e. that the word בקרבך is equivalent in numerical value (324) of the words זו האשה (324)**“this is the woman,” i.e. the woman experiencing the immaculate conception, who gave birth to the founder of Christianity** who was halachically a Jew. Clearly, the author, living as he did in Christian Spain in the 14th century where the Inquisition held sway, did not want to expose himself to the accusation by the Inquisition that he had labeled that man as a false prophet. Chumash editions printed in predominantly Christian countries either omit the author’s comment on this verse altogether or present it in an entirely unintelligible form i.e. that the numerical value of the word בקרבך=the numerical value of the word זו. Ed.]

it seems @Robev 's answer is an additional factor that connects woman and the word